# Unique minimizer of $\|x\|_{\mathcal A}$ subject to $\Phi x=\Phi x_0$

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 2.3 of the paper [Simple bounds for recovering low-complexity models](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1474).

The authors want to find bounds on the numbers of rows $m$ of $\Phi$ to ensure that $x_0$ is the unique minimizer of the following problem
$$\tag{1.1}\label{eq}
\min \|x\|_{\mathcal A} \text{ subject to } \Phi x=\Phi x_0.
$$
Where $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal A}$ is a norm with some properties which encourage solutions which conform to some notion of simplicity.

In Definition 2.2, they say

> A norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal A}$ is decomposable at $x_0$ if there is a subspace $T\subset \mathbb R^n$ and a vector $e\in T$ such that the subdifferential at $x_0$ has the form
>   $$
> \partial \|x_0\|_{\mathcal A}=\left\{z\in\mathbb R^n:\mathcal P_T(z)=e \text{ and } \|\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(z)\|_{\mathcal A}^* \le 1\right\}
> $$
>   and for any $w\in T^\bot$, we have
>   $$
> \|w\|_{\mathcal A}=\sup_{v\in T^\bot,\|v\|_{\mathcal A}^* \le 1}\langle v,w \rangle
> $$
>   Above, $\mathcal P_T$ (resp. $\mathcal P_{T^\bot}$ is the orthogonal projection onto $T$ (resp. orthogonal complement of $T$).

In Lemma 2.3, they state the following

> Suppose that $\Phi$ is injective on the subspace $T$ and that there exists a vector $y$ in the image of $\Phi*$ (the adjoint of $\Phi$) obeying
>
> 1. $\mathcal P_T(y)=e$, where $e$ is as in definition 2.2.
> 2. $\|\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(y)\|_{\mathcal A}^* < 1$.
>
> Then $x_0$ is the unique minimizer of \eqref{eq}.

Here is the proof they provide

> The proof is an adaptation from a standard argument. Consider any perturbation $x_0+h$ where $\Phi h=0$. Since the norm is decomposable, there exists a $v\in T^\bot$ such that $\|v\|_{\mathcal A}^*\le 1$ and $\langle v,\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)\rangle=\|\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)\|_{\mathcal A}$. Moreover, we have that $e+v$ is a subgradient of $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal A}$ at $x_0$. Hence,
>   \begin{align*}
> \|x_0+h\|_{\mathcal A} & \ge \|x_0\|_{\mathcal A}+\langle e+v,h\rangle \\
> & = \|x_0\|_{\mathcal A}+\langle e+v-y,h\rangle \\
> & = \|x_0\|_{\mathcal A}+\langle v-\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(y),\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)\rangle \\
> & \ge \|x_0\|_{\mathcal A}+(1-\|\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(y)\|_{\mathcal A}^*)\|\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)\|_{\mathcal A}.
> \end{align*}
>   Since $\|\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(y)\|_{\mathcal A}^*$ is strictly less than one, this last inequality holds strictly unless $\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)=0$. But if $\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)=0$, then $\mathcal P_T(h)$ must also be zero because we have assumed that $\Phi$ is injective on $T$. This means that $h$ is zero proving that $x_0$ is the unique minimizer of \eqref{eq}.

Things I do not understand:

1. Why $e+v$ is a subgradient of $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal A}$ ?
2. How $\langle e+v,h\rangle=\langle e+v-y,h\rangle=\langle v-\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(y),\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)\rangle$ ?
3. Not sure about the last argument : since $\Phi$ is injective on $T$, we have $\mathcal P_{T^\bot}(h)=0\implies\mathcal P_{T}(h)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that $e+v$ satisfies the definition given in 2.2 since $e \in T$ and the norm of $v$ is less than or equal to 1, so $e + v$ must be in the subgradient.
2. $\langle e+v,h\rangle = \langle e+v-y,h\rangle$ because $\langle y,h\rangle = 0$ (since $y$ is in the image of the adjoint while $h$ is an element of the nullspace). This follows from the fact that
   $$Ah = 0 \iff (Ah,y) = 0 ~~\forall y \iff (h,A^*y)=0 ~~\forall y \iff h\perp \mathrm{Im}(A^*)$$

   (i)  The first reason for $\langle e+v-y,h\rangle = \langle v - \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(y), \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(h)\rangle$ is, since $e = \mathcal P_T(y)$, $$y - e = y - \mathcal P_T(y) = \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(y)$$

   (ii)  Secondly $v, \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(y) \in T^\perp$ so that $$\langle v - \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(y), h\rangle = \langle v - \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(y), \mathcal P_{T}(h) + \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(h)\rangle = \langle v - \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(y), \mathcal P_{T^\perp}(h)\rangle$$
3. $\mathcal P_{T^\perp}(h) = 0$ means that $h$ lies orthogonal to $T^\perp$ $-$ i.e., $h$ must lie in $T$. Since $\Phi$ is injective on $T$, it follows by definition of injectivity that $h \equiv 0$.